# Validate input field depends on other html elmement jQuery validate function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I m trying to validate to validate the input depends on other html element.
If the other html is empty it should validate the input and if not the not valid.

This is my HTML:

```
<input id="oka_rijkregister_last" name="oka_rijksregisternummer_last" type="text">
<span id="oka_rijkregister_last_BtnVal" class="error_msg"></span>
```

I have a separate function on input which validate the input data, if data is not correct it displays the error message in span element else remains empty.

Here is my JS code which i am trying to validate depends on span element.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    oka_rijksregisternummer_last : {
    minlength: {
      param:17,
      depends: function (element) {
          if($("#oka_rijkregister_last_BtnVal").html() === "") {
            return true;
          }
          else {
            return false;
          }
      }
    }
   }
  }
});
```

My code is working till param 17 and rest it ignores.
Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just so I understand, you're trying to enforce a minlength of 17 chars on the oka_rijksregisternummer_last field only if the span below it (which I understand to be the error message field) is empty? And you're using the jquery-validation package?

Comment: @Travis yes exactly. Actually input has 17 character code which has some validation via php script. jQuery validating only the minlength here and the error message coming from the php script. I want check if length is 17 and and there is no error message shows in span.